# How to Check Hidden Value

Tags: php, forms

I'm beginner on php. I'm making a basic number guess game. There are 2 levels. In `level1.php` I send user input to `formprocess.php`

```
echo "<form name = \"myfirstform\" action  = \"formprocess.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo "Enter Integer Between 1-5<br>";
echo "<input type = \"text\" name = \"firstdata\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
```

in `formprocess.php` i check if the value is correct

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['wins']) || !isset($_SESSION['losses'])) {
    $_SESSION['wins'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['losses'] = 0;
}
$random = rand(1, 5);
if ($_POST["firstdata"] == $random){
$_SESSION['wins']++; 
 echo "<h1><font color=\"green\">Congrulations!</h1></font><br>";
else{
$_SESSION['losses']++;
echo "<h1><font color=\"red\">Nope wrong answer</h1></font><br>";
```

It works pretty good (i skipped other codes) Now i want to send the player to level2.php if his answer is correct. I tried to do it with hidden input like this:

```
echo "<form name = \"mysecondform\" action  = \"level2.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"seconddata\" value=\"1\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"Go to Level2\">";
```

In `level2.php` my codes are:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["seconddata"] == 1){
echo "<html><head><title>Calculator Game From 1998</title></head><body>";
echo "<h1>Please Guess The Answer-Level2</h1>";
echo "<form name = \"myfirstform\" action  = \"formprocess.php\" method = \"POST\">";
echo "Enter Integer Between 1-10<br>";
echo "<input type = \"text\" name = \"firstdata\">";
echo "<br> <input type= \"submit\" value = \"submit\">";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body></html>";
}
else{
echo "You didn't finish level1"
} 
?>
```

Even if answer is correct, there is nothing in this page. I changed `1` value with `"1"` not working again. What is the problem on there

Comment: post full code, and check with developer tools if any js errors.Put error_reporting on

Comment: What does print_r($_POST) say in level2.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

silly mistake

i should have write

```
echo "You didn't finish level1"
```

instead of

```
else{
echo "You didn't finish level1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your page appear blank is maybe for a php error, put the next code in the top of your php script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```